# Execute a shell file from java passing int and string arguments

Tags: java, shell, jakarta-ee

I am trying to execute a shell file by passing the arguments variables from Java.

I want to call the shell file script.sh from the java code passing the above variables like start, end , country along with it.

```
int start = 10;
int end  = 100;
String country = India;
String scriptlocation =  scriptloc+"/script.sh";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(scriptlocation);
processBuilder.environment().put("start", start);
processBuilder.environment().put("end", end);
processBuilder.environment().put("country", country);
```

where in the start and end are integers and the country is a string
 variable.. So the above method doesn't work for int variables.

I also tried the below way

```
ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh",
                                      "-c",
                                      "start=start end=end  country=country scriptlocation");
```

I m not sure this method will work or not .Because it has to take the values of the variables like 10 , 100 and india for the start, end and country variables.. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

`put` is used to set environment variables not command line argument (refer to shell manuals to understand what environment variables are).

You need to pass one string for each argument. Passing `"/bin/sh", "-c", "start=start end=end country=country scriptlocation"` makes the shell receiving 3 args. Moreover you also need to convert your `int`s to strings.
I don't know exactly how your script receives it arguments, but something like this should work:

```
new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/sh", "-c", "start="+start, "end="+end, "country="+country, scriptlocation");
```